# Rotate/Spin Object with form input & slider

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an object called #person that I need to rotate from -180 to 180 degrees with input from a slider. I have the slider working with the input box synced up to show the current angle value and a function I attempted to write but it's not working. I'm trying to use style.transform. Using  bootstrap and jQueryUI in the project, a solution involving those two frameworks instead of standard javascript would also help.

```
HTML

<label for="angleSlider" class="form-label">Rotation Angle</label>
    <form>
        <input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="thetaRange" min="-180" max="180" value="0"
        oninput="this.form.thetaInput.value=this.value" />
        <input type="number" id="thetaInput" min="-180" max="180" value="0"
        oninput="this.form.thetaRange.value=this.value" />
    </form>
```

```
Javascript

function rotatePerson() {
        const person = document.getElementById("person");
        var angle = document.getElementById("thetaRange");
        person.style.transform = "rotate(angle deg)"
    }
```

Comment: This is not a jQuery UI question nor a jQuery question. You may want to consider adjusting your Tags.

Comment: @Twisty looking for any way to do this. what I did was in plain JS but it also didn't work, just trying to give an idea of what I tried first. if there's a solution that involved using a jQueryUI or jQuery property then I welcome it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following jQuery example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#thetaRange").on("input", function() {
    var angle = $(this).val() + "deg";
    $(".angle").html(angle);
    $(".person").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");
  });
});
```

```css
.viewspace {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}

.person {
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #eef;
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

.angle {
  width: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewspace">
  <div class="person">
  </div>
</div>
<label for="angleSlider" class="form-label">Rotation Angle</label>
<input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="thetaRange" min="-180" max="180" value="0" />
<span class="angle">0deg</span>
```

This rotates the element based on the Value of the Range Input on `input` event.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but you need to make a few changes for this to be valid JavaScript.

Your code `"rotate(angle deg)"` is setting the `transform` property to literally have the word "angle", rather than including the angle number you wanted. To include the angle number you can use the string interpolation feature of JavaScript, which combines text with a variable value: `` `rotate(${angle}deg)` `` Note the use of backticks `` ` `` which activate the string interpolation feature. You can read more about this feature in the guide on MDN: [Expressions in text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting#embedded_expressions) or [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Also, you need to use `.value` to access the number value of the input or slider objects. I've used `const angle = thetaRange.value` to do this. You can see more examples of accessing the value of an input on MDN, such as on the [reference page for <range>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#setting_step_to_any).

Finally, you will need to add event listeners to trigger the `rotatePerson` function when the text input or slider are changed. If you don't already have those, you can add them with this code:

```
const thetaRange = document.getElementById("thetaRange");
const thetaInput = document.getElementById("thetaInput");
thetaRange.addEventListener("input", () => rotatePerson());
thetaInput.addEventListener("input", () => rotatePerson());
```

Putting it all together:

```js
const person = document.getElementById("person")
const thetaRange = document.getElementById("thetaRange")
const thetaInput = document.getElementById("thetaInput")

// Adding the event listeners to make it rotate when the slider or input changes
thetaRange.addEventListener("input", () => rotatePerson())
thetaInput.addEventListener("input", () => rotatePerson())

// Function that sets the rotation
function rotatePerson() {
  const angle = thetaRange.value
  person.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div><label for="angleSlider" class="form-label">Rotation Angle</label></div>
  <input type="range" class="form-range w-75" id="thetaRange" min="-180" max="180" value="0"
        oninput="this.form.thetaInput.value=this.value" />
  <input type="number" id="thetaInput" min="-180" max="180" value="0"
        oninput="this.form.thetaRange.value=this.value" />
</form>

<!-- Placeholder for the person element -->
<div id="person" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, red); height: 100px; width: 200px"></div>
```

^ Click run code snippet to see it in action!

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet you provided is almost correct, but there are a couple of issues in the last line of the JavaScript code. Here is the corrected version with an explanation:

```
function rotatePerson() {
    const person = document.getElementById("person");
    var angle = document.getElementById("thetaRange").value; // Get the value of the angle
    person.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"; // Concatenate the angle variable into the transform property
}
```

**Explanation :**

**1.** The `rotatePerson` function selects the element with the ID "person" using `getElementById` and assigns it to the `person` variable.

**2.** Next, it retrieves the value of the angle from the element with the ID "thetaRange" using `getElementById` and accessing the `value` property. This value represents the current angle selected on the slider.

**3.** Finally, the code sets the `style.transform` property of the `person` element to `rotate(" + angle + "deg)`. This dynamically applies the rotation to the `person` element, using the `angle` value in degrees obtained from the slider.

By calling the `rotatePerson` function whenever the slider value changes, the person element will rotate according to the selected angle.

Comment: can't get it to work in my code. Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Temur! Please keep in mind that on Stack Overflow, using AI like ChatGPT is not allowed. If you wrote this answer yourself, my apologies, and you can ignore this comment. More information about ChatGPT here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/13339698